# Custom Post Meta on a Different Page?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I'm using this code to call some custom post meta named port_excerpt:

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo get_post_meta($postid, 'port_excerpt', true);
?>
```

This works like a dream when used on the template it is intended for: http://themeforward.com/demo2/portfolio/new-one/.  But the custom post template I am using (as in 3.0 custom post templates) is being used for a portfolio, as a result I also need to call this on my portfolio page: http://themeforward.com/demo2/portfolio/

How do I call port_excerpt, which is meta contained within a custom post, on the portfolio page above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put this inside the loop running on the portfolio page.

```
echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'port_excerpt', true );
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your post loop, use $post->ID instead of $wp_query->post->ID. If you could post the loop you're using it would be clearer.